# How to stretch multiple inline-blocks to fill all the space of parent?

Tags: css

after lot of searching, I haven't found a solution to my problem, so it's time to ask here.

Here's the problem: I have a block-rendered div and a variable number of buttons rendered as inline-block inside that div. I would like those buttons to stretch evenly to fill al the space of a parent, like, if I have 3 buttons they would stretch to 33% width, if 2 that would be 50%, and so on.

Can that be done with pure css? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use css [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
.btn-holder {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: flex;
}

.btn-holder button {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-holder">
  <button type="button">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button">Button 3</button>
</div>
<div class="btn-holder">
  <button type="button">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button">Button 3</button>
  <button type="button">Button 4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That helped splendidly. Thank you very much.

Comment: **To the Downvoter:** Kindly leave a comment describing reason for your downvote. This will help me to know what is wrong with this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could set the parent to `display: table` and the children to `display: table-cell`.

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.container .cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
2 cells
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">2</div>
</div>

<br>3 cells
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">2</div>
  <div class="cell">3</div>
</div>

<br>5 cells
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">2</div>
  <div class="cell">3</div>
  <div class="cell">4</div>
  <div class="cell">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work with elements that you want to keep in the "inline-block behaviour", ie each of them spanning to a width related to its contents. The "display: table;" solution makes the elements equal in width...